# Appendix will not work at all, please help.

Tags: appendices, input, import

I would like to include an appendix (just one appendix) in my thesis, following the bibliography. I am using book class, and have each chapter in a separate file.

When I try to add an appendix, the entire document will no longer compile. At all.

Here's what I have, including the things I have tried that have not worked:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import} 
%\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix} % to add appendix %% <- this did not work
\usepackage{subfiles} % to help manage subfiles (i.e. chapters) 
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\input{title.tex}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\import{Chapters/}{1_Introduction.tex}
\bibliographystyle{apa} 
\bibliography{mybibliography}  
%\chapter{APPENDIX} %did not work
%\import{Chapters/}{Z_Appendix.tex} % did not work
%
%\appendix % 1a/3a didn't work
%\chapter{Appendix} %2a/3a didn't work
%\input{Chapters/}{Z_Appendix.tex} %3a/3a didn't work
\end{document}
```

I hope that's clear--this is my first time posting here, so if more info is let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What exactly does "the entire document will no longer compile" entail? Which error messages, if any, do you get? Does the document correctly as long as `Z_Appendix.tex` isn't imported? Did you check the contents of `Z_Appendix.tex` for corrupted input?

Comment: The first parts/chapters.whatever are loaded using `import`, the appendix uses `input` which expectsjust one argument.

Comment: @Mico, When I compile my document, I get the error message "compile error" and near the

Comment: (Sorry, hit enter too soon and took to long to make my edits) @Mico, When I compile my document, I get the error message "compile error", then "\input{appendix.tex} File ended while scanning use of \next. I suspect you have forgotten a }."   and near the `\input{Z_Appendix.tex}` command in my main file, the error message says "file ended while scanning use of \next".  @Johannes_B, thanks, I tried changing to  `input` and using one argument (`\appendix` `\chapter{Appendix}` `\input{Z_Appendix.tex}`, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is not direct answer to your questions, however it can help you, if you are willing to change the way how to compose your thesis.

In similar cases I use master document something as follows:

```
\includeonly{
    chapter-1/file-1,
    chapter-2/file-2,   
    chapter-3/file-3,   
    ....
    chapterApp/apendix-A,
    bibliography}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \documentclass[<options>]{book}
    ...

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{plain}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \frontmatter
\tableofcontents                                
\cleardoublepage
    \listoffigures                                  
\clearpage
    \listoftables                                   
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \mainmatter
    \pagestyle{...}
    \chapterstyle{...}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \include{chapter-1/file-1}
    \include{chapter-2/file-2} 
    ....
    \include{chapterApp/apendixA}
    \include{ch10/sdv-ka-ch11ZigBee}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \backmatter
    \include{bibliography} 
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{document}
```

This, "classical" approach is many time proven. With commenting of files in part `includeonly` you can compile desired part of thesis with working hyperlinks between chapters. As shown, files are stored in directories `chapter-x`, where I usually form sub directories for images and tables. For they I use standalone package which enable to draw images or write table without of use main document. They are included in files with `input` or `includegraphics`, depends of number of them.