# How to add a table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I know there are many answers to  Table of contents but I am a beginner and just been using LaTeX, Texmaker for the past 3 days.
I am writing my thesis and I am using the Report as document class. I also have created separate `.tex` file for each chapter so I am able to work more compactly. I have also managed to use inputfile and get these into my Master document. So the idea is I write my chapters, create my sections and subsection and then run Quick Build and then have all imported into my Master document. It is working okay. But I cannot get the Table of contents.

All I want is what everyone wants. Just for the toc to be able to link to the individual `.tex` Chapter files I have and list the Chapter numbers and Section and subsection numbers to the pages they are on in the Master document.

```
1   Chapter 01: INTRODUCTION TO THESIS ............................................ 4
    1.1     WHAT ARE FOURIER TRANSFORMS ........................................... 4
    1.2     WHY DO WE NEED THEM ................................................... 5

2   Chapter 02: HOW TO CREATE TRANSFORMS EFFICIENTLY .............................. 6
    2.1     APPLYING A DISCRETE THEOREM ........................................... 7
```

And so on. Basically all the subsections are held in the specific separate `.tex` file for each chapter. Can someone please help. I really do appreciate it and sorry for being so slow in this!

Comment: have you used the command `\tableofcontents` in your document?

Comment: if by "separate files" (you should always show an example code to save us guessing) you mean each starts with `\documentclass` do not do that just use `\documentclass` once, in your main file.

Comment: @AdH Welcome to TeX.SX! Just issue the command `\tableofcontents` where you want your TOC appear.

Comment: @AboAmmar, see my answer to question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249641/appendix-will-not-work-at-all-please-help/249649#249649, maybe it will give you idea, how to organize your work and solve your problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think that can be the case if `\input`ting the files is working correctly?

Comment: @cfr true but OP didn't say  `\input` explicitly....

Comment: I have solved it!!! Thanks for all your help..Now that I am done with the basic layout I am typing my document...Now I am on to Mathematical symbols for Integration, differentiation and the sorts..such long formulae I have to derive..But I guess I can copy paste and work..more tedious I guess that's all...THANKS AGAIN FOLKS!!